# Pass session values to other page

Tags: php, session

I have two pages: order.php and checkout.php. I have 3 items in the order page and I want to pass quantity of the items to the checkout page.

I guess the problem is with `isset($_POST['Submit'])`. My guess is that it still goes straight to the checkout page when I press submit without putting values to session variables.

I have been trying to pass the values from order like this:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lomake-esimerkki</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // raportoidaan virheet
ini_set('display_errors','On'); // näytetään ne myös

echo <<<END
<form action="checkout.php" 
method="post">
<p>Gaming Computer - 5 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara1" /></label></p>
<p>Frigge - 10 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara2" /></label></p>
<p>IKEA-table - 15 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara3" /></label></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order"/></p>
<input type=hidden name=price1 value=5>
<input type=hidden name=price2 value=10>
<input type=hidden name=price3 value=15>
</form>
<hr />
END;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION["maara1"] = $_POST["maara1"];
    $_SESSION["maara2"] = $_POST["maara2"];
    $_SESSION["maara3"] = $_POST["maara3"];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here in checkout I'm trying to print one session value as test:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lomake-esimerkki</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // raportoidaan virheet
ini_set('display_errors','On'); // näytetään ne myös

print ($_SESSION["maara1"]);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and did it like this. With two button and it is also more close to webstore now. So I press first button to add the quantity of the items and at the same time it sets session variables. Then I press second button to proceed to the second page which is checkout. What you guys think?

First page:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lomake-esimerkki</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // raportoidaan virheet
ini_set('display_errors','On'); // näytetään ne myös

echo <<<END
<form action="teht7.php" 
method="post">
<p>Gaming Computer - 5 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara1" /></label></p>
<p>Fridge - 10 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara2" /></label></p>
<p>IKEA-table - 15 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara3" /></label></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Valitse tuotteet"/></p>

</form>
<hr />

<form action="teht7_kassa.php" 
method="post">
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Siirry kasssalle"/></p>
<input type=hidden name=price1 value=5>
<input type=hidden name=price2 value=10>
<input type=hidden name=price3 value=15>
</form>
<hr />

END;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $ostostenmaara = $_POST["maara1"] + $_POST["maara2"] + $_POST["maara3"];
    print ("Ostoskorissa on: $ostostenmaara tuotetta");
    $_SESSION["maara1"] = $_POST["maara1"];
    $_SESSION["maara2"] = $_POST["maara2"];
    $_SESSION["maara3"] = $_POST["maara3"];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Second page:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lomake-esimerkki</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // raportoidaan virheet
ini_set('display_errors','On'); // näytetään ne myös




    $maara1 = $_SESSION["maara1"];
    $maara2 = $_SESSION["maara2"];
    $maara3 = $_SESSION["maara3"];
$summa = $_POST["price1"]*$maara1+$_POST["price2"]*$maara2+$_POST["price3"]*$maara3;
    print ("Ostostesi yhteissumma on: $summa euroa");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

> *"I guess the problem is with `isset($_POST['Submit'])`."*

Yes, the problem is with `if (isset($_POST['Submit']))`

Your submit button is named `submit` instead of `Submit`.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order"/>
```

Change it to

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Order"/>
```

- They are case-sensitive.

Or leave it the way it is and change

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

- Either method will work. You just need to make them both (*letter cases*) match.

---

What is happening is, PHP is looking for a named element called `Submit`.

That alone would have and *should have* thrown:

> Undefined index Submit...

---

***Sidenote:***

I noticed:

```
<input type=hidden name=price1 value=5>
```

and other inputs.

I would suggest that you use quotes around it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price1" value="5">
```

while doing the same for the others, as it could have adverse effects and/or unexpected results.
I have seen that happen before.

---

**Edit:**

You'll need to move this whole block in your second page and not be in the first page.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION["maara1"] = $_POST["maara1"];
    $_SESSION["maara2"] = $_POST["maara2"];
    $_SESSION["maara3"] = $_POST["maara3"];
}
```

then do `print ($_SESSION["maara1"]);` from there.

Your first page does not recognize the POST variables because they have not been set.

---

**Edit #2**:

You could try setting a value `value="{$_SESSION["maara1"]}"` to your inputs.

I.e.:

Sidenote: You could try `<form action="" method="post">` instead of `<form action="checkout.php" method="post">`

However, I'm unsure if the following is what you're looking to get. It does work if `action=""` but it won't work trying to get a value before it has been set. That's not how sessions work.

It's kind of like expecting an `A+` in a test you haven't written yet, *if I can say.*

```
echo <<<END
<form action="checkout.php" method="post">
<p>Gaming Computer - 5 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara1" value="{$_SESSION["maara1"]}" /></label></p>
<p>Frigge - 10 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara2" /></label></p>
<p>IKEA-table - 15 e/kpl <label>How many? <input type="text" name="maara3" /></label></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Order"/></p>
<input type=hidden name=price1 value=5>
<input type=hidden name=price2 value=10>
<input type=hidden name=price3 value=15>
</form>
<hr />
END;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$_SESSION["maara1"] = $_POST["maara1"];

$mar1 = $_SESSION["maara1"];

echo $mar1;

}
```

---

But as you said in a comment: *"what is the point of me using session variables on second page then if I can refer them from $_POST anyways?"*

- **A:** Exactly.

Comment: Actually this doesnt help. The reason is that when I press the submit button it goes straight to the checkout.php without looking the order.php again, right? Like you can see from line <form action="checkout.php" method="post">

Comment: The point is that I have to set session stuff in the first page and not in the second one

Comment: You'll need to move this whole block `if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION["maara1"] = $_POST["maara1"];
    $_SESSION["maara2"] = $_POST["maara2"];
    $_SESSION["maara3"] = $_POST["maara3"];
}` in your second page and not be in the first page. Your first page does not recognize the POST variables because they have not been set. @user3790046 - see my edit.

Comment: So there isnt anyway to make it so that it sets session stuff in first page?

Comment: I mean what is the point of me using session variables on second page then if I can refer them from $_POST anyways?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That's just how sessions work unfortunately. @user3790046

Comment: @user3790046 I've made an **Edit #2:** but not sure if that'll work for what you want to do. Try it out. Yet again, sessions don't work that way. Something needs to be first set before assignment can be done. It's kind of like expecting an `A+` in a test you haven't written yet, *if I can say*. ;)